# How long will it take for the terminated instance to get removed from the console?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

*Documentation says ([Terminating an Instance](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/Compute/Tasks/terminatinginstance.htm)), Terminated instances temporarily remain in the list of instances with the status Terminated*.

Is there any particular time limit for the terminated instance to be removed from the console?

Comment: It takes 24 hours to remove from console.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The billing stops when the terminate API call succeeds. The instance should go to terminating while it cleans up resources and shuts things down. Currently it is configured so that once it has successfully transitioned to terminated it will remain visible in the console for around 12 hours.

Comment: Is there any trick to make them disappear sooner?
I'm working on video tutorials and i'd be nice if I could start from a clean slate once I terminate instances without having to wait 12h.

Comment: @MrE If it's only for the visuals, you can either delete that row in the web page's source code using inspect element; or you can use adblock to hide that particular row. If you're making a tutorial, I however see no harm in showing a terminating instance - That's a real life scenario after all!!

Comment: Is this applicable for boot volumes too?